# UITapGestureRecognizer not working until I scroll all the way to the bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have added a UITapGestureRecognizer to a label in a UITableViewCell, however the click only works after I scroll to the bottom of the table.

Once I scroll to the bottom the tap works perfectly and performs the segue, but until I do, it does not call the function.

I have verified that the if statement does evaluate as true before I scroll, so the recognizer is there, but it just doesn't work.

Any ideas as to why would be greatly appreciated.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    for viewToRemove in cell.subviews {
        viewToRemove.removeFromSuperview();
    }
    
    let result = self.ResultArray[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary;
    let width = self.frame.width;
    
    let rawTime = result["LogInDTM"] as? String;
    let rawUNIT = result[“unit”] as? String;
    let rawPersonID = result["PERS_ID"] as? String;
    let rawName = result["PERS_NAME"] as? String;
    let rawVehicle = result["Vehicle_ID"] as? String;
    let rawCall = result["CALL_NO"] as? String;
    
    var CleanVehicle = ""
    
    if let tmpVehicle = rawVehicle {
        CleanVehicle = tmpVehicle
    }
    
    var CleanCall = ""
    
    if let tmpCall = rawCall {
        CleanCall = tmpCall
    }
    
    var CleanUnit = ""
    
    if let tmpUnit = rawUNIT {
        CleanUnit = tmpUnit
    }
    
    //print(result);
    
    let cellView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 30));
    cellView.backgroundColor = .black;
    cellView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    cellView.layer.masksToBounds = true;
  
    let UnitLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 2, y: 0, width: width*0.15, height: 30));
    UnitLabel.textColor = .white;
    UnitLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    UnitLabel.layer.borderColor = self.configuration.SOOrange.cgColor;
    UnitLabel.text = " "+CleanUnit;
    UnitLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: UIFont.Weight(rawValue: 400));
    UnitLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
    cellView.addSubview(UnitLabel);
    
    let SubjectLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: (width*0.15)+2, y: 0, width: width*0.4, height: 30));
    SubjectLabel.textColor = .white;
    SubjectLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    SubjectLabel.layer.borderColor = self.configuration.SOOrange.cgColor;
    SubjectLabel.text = " "+rawName!;
    SubjectLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: UIFont.Weight(rawValue: 400));
    SubjectLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
    cellView.addSubview(SubjectLabel);
    
    let VehicleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: (width*0.55)+2, y: 0, width: width*0.2, height: 30));
    VehicleLabel.textColor = .white;
    VehicleLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    VehicleLabel.layer.borderColor = self.configuration.SOOrange.cgColor;
    VehicleLabel.text = " "+CleanVehicle;
    VehicleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: UIFont.Weight(rawValue: 400));
    VehicleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
    cellView.addSubview(VehicleLabel);
    
    let CallLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: (width*0.75)+2, y: 0, width: width*0.24, height: 30));
    CallLabel.textColor = .white;
    CallLabel.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    CallLabel.layer.borderColor = self.configuration.SOOrange.cgColor;
    CallLabel.text = " "+CleanCall;
    CallLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: UIFont.Weight(rawValue: 400));
    CallLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
    
    if(CleanCall != ""){
        print(CleanCall);
        let callTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.openCall(_:)))
        CallLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        CallLabel.addGestureRecognizer(callTap)
    }
    
    
    
    cellView.addSubview(CallLabel);
    
    
    
    cell.addSubview(cellView);
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This is not a good approach... In `cellForRowAt` you should only dequeue a cell and set its data (label text, maybe colors, etc). You should **not** be adding / removing subviews or gesture recognizers. Will every cell have a "UnitLabel", "SubjectLabel", "VehicleLabel" and "CallLabel"? If so, you should create a custom cell with those labels already in place and only set their `.text` property. Your `UITapGestureRecognizer` should also be part of the cell class.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I attempted to use a separate class for the UITableViewCell, the cell ended up being 80% of the width of the table and I could not seem to make it match.

I decided to use didSelectRowAt and just allow the whole row to be selected. This accomplished the requirement, but I don't know exactly why the original code didn't work.